# How to control the placement of GAC for IIS managed modules?

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, gac

I need to develop a module for IIS. It's compiled as Strong Named and signed. 'gacutil.exe' placed it into the GAC succesfully. But if I'm trying to visit localhost IIS throws exception:

```
Could not load type 'NameSpace.Name'.
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'NameSpace.Name'.
```

where NameSpace and Name are from my module's sourcecode.
I believe IIS looks for modules at C:\Windows\assembly (where modules are for .Net 2.0), but I can see my module at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32.
How should I tell IIS to use another GAC folder?

Comment: You can't unless you run IIS using a .NET 4 application pool. Your dll is targeting the wrong version of the framework if you need it to use it with .NET 2.0.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. I need to use my module with .Net v.4.5